# com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type.1

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

This problem arose to me when I responded to include the names of the users that I contacted. I want to include them in the list from the database, but the problem occurred as shown in the picture below the question.

**the errors**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.hussainhasson.sayhi, PID: 21896
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.hussainhasson.sayhi.ModelClass.chatlist
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(CustomClassMapper.java:436)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(CustomClassMapper.java:232)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(CustomClassMapper.java:80)
    at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:203)
    at com.hussainhasson.sayhi.Fragments.chatFragment$onCreateView$1.onDataChange(chatFragment.kt:56)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:75)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:55)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:280)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6710)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

---

### code fragment

This is the code for listening and parsing Firebase data

```kotlin
package com.hussainhasson.sayhi.Fragments

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener
import com.hussainhasson.sayhi.AdappterClasses.UserAdappter
import com.hussainhasson.sayhi.ModelClass.Users
import com.hussainhasson.sayhi.ModelClass.chat
import com.hussainhasson.sayhi.ModelClass.chatlist
import com.hussainhasson.sayhi.R

class chatFragment : Fragment()
{

    private var userAdappter: UserAdappter?=null
    private var musers:List<Users>?=null
    private var userschatlist:List<chatlist>?=null
    lateinit var recycler_view_chatlist:RecyclerView
    private var firebaseUser:FirebaseUser?=null


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
       val view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat, container, false)

        recycler_view_chatlist=view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_chatlist)
        recycler_view_chatlist.setHasFixedSize(true)
        recycler_view_chatlist.layoutManager=LinearLayoutManager(context)

        firebaseUser=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
        userschatlist=ArrayList()
        val ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
            .child("Chatlists").child(firebaseUser!!.uid)

ref.addValueEventListener(object :ValueEventListener{
    override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot)
    {

        (userschatlist as ArrayList).clear()
            for (shot in p0.children)
            {

                    val chatlist1=shot.getValue(chatlist::class.java)
                    (userschatlist as ArrayList).add(chatlist1!!)


            }

        retrivechatlist()

    }

    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

    }


})
        return view
    }

private fun retrivechatlist()
{
    musers=ArrayList()
    val ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Users")

    ref.addValueEventListener(object :ValueEventListener{
        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
            (musers as ArrayList).clear()
            for (shot in p0.children)
            {
                val user=shot.getValue(Users::class.java)

                for (eachchatlist in userschatlist!!)
                {
                    if (user!!.getUID().equals(eachchatlist.getid()))
                    {
                        (musers as ArrayList).add(user)
                    }

                }

            }
            userAdappter= UserAdappter(context!!,(musers as ArrayList<Users>),true)
            recycler_view_chatlist.adapter=userAdappter

        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
        }

    })

}

}
```

### code  class chatlists

Class that represents the structure of Firebase db data

```kotlin
package com.hussainhasson.sayhi.ModelClass

class chatlist
{
    private var id:String=""

    constructor()
    constructor(id: String) {
        this.id = id
    }


    fun getid ():String?
    {
        return id
    }
    fun setid (id : String)
    {
        this.id =id
    }
}
```

[firebase database see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcrBU.png)

Comment: Your database has the wrong type(in the string format) of data that's why it's crashing

Comment: What is the correct solution?

Comment: Can you also post your database value? So that same can be validated if your DB contains the wrong data type or not?

Comment: My database I need by chatlists and it only contains id And you have checked the Datasnapshot value I found it actually fetches the user id But in this line of code the program stops val chatlist1 = shot.getValue (chatlist :: class.java) in code fragment

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your comment. Without a screenshot of your DB, it's really hard to suggest anything

Comment: Okay
I took a screenshot and uploaded it in the post you can see the image

Answer (score 0):

Hi it is now clear from your Firebase database image that you have mixed type of data like for user ending with userId "...fQ2" you have child as String while your code is expecting chatlist class that's why it is crashing.
To solve this issue you may delete inconsistent node or handle both type of data type.
Also your naming convention is wrong and indentation also seems to be wrong. You may want to update those to make your question more understandable.

Comment: I did not understand what you mean

Comment: You have inconsistent data structure. Also for starters please read how serialization and deserialization works and then how realtime firebase db works